# Typescript error when using observable.map() instead of asMap()

Tags: javascript, typescript, mobx

In version 2 with `asMap`, I used to initialize an empty observable maps like this:

```
class Store{
    @observable private collection: ObservableMap<SomeType> = asMap()
}
```

Since `asMap` is depreciated in version 3, I need to use `observable.map()`. But it gives an `TS2322` error if I write like this:

```
@observable private collection: ObservableMap<SomeType> = observable.map({})
```

The only way I can think of to avoid this error:

```
class Store{
    @observable private collection: ObservableMap<SomeType>;
    constructor(props: Props) {
      super(props);
      let fakeObj = {} as SomeType
      this.collection = observable.map({fake:fakeObj})
    }
}
```

Is this the only way to avoid the type error without using `any`?

Comment: could `@observable private collection: ObservableMap<SomeType> = observable.map<SomeType>()` work for you?